# Steering wheel controls with zener diode?

Tags: arduino, resistors, diodes, adc, automotive

I am looking at my steering wheel schematics and trying to find what are these zener diode doing there?

I want to be sure there's no problem feeding 5V from an Arduino to check the ADC values without having 12V from the control backlights backfeeding into the resistor network.

I measured with a multimeter I could get any voltage at all which is good.

[image: schematics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a more inclusive schematic to give it context, I'd guess that the Signal- line is actually ground, and the buttons are read by measuring the resistance from Signal+ to ground.  The bottom diode would likely be to protect the backlight from voltage spikes.

The one on top I'm less sure of.  It may be protecting from spikes from nearby circuitry, or protecting from spikes on Signal+ from developing sufficient voltage to damage the switches.  Since it only has voltage on it when no switch is closed, it may just be regulating the "default" level at which no switch closure is detected.

Comment: Thanks! Automotive wiring diagram are very basic. I'm even surprised they listed resistor values that are on the switch pcb. I guess these diodes won't create any problem with the arduino 5V ADC.

Answer (score 0):

The resistors are a voltage divider. The head unit reads voltages from the steering wheel controls. I assume the zener diodes regulate the voltage to the voltage divider otherwise operation of controls would be erratic.